# how can i use the is set methode to difference comment and post

Tags: laravel, post, comments

I get the error below when I add a comment in the table notifications in my database to notify users by the add a comment;

> Undefined index: ad_object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\layouts\app.blad 
>   here is my app.blade

```
@foreach(Auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
     <li>
         <a href="#">{{$notification->data['user_name']}} posted a new ad "{{$notification->data['ad_object']}}"</a>
     </li>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add the portion of your controller that lead to the view to the question

Answer (score 0):

Adding what `$notification->data` has would've helped out

You can try this

```
@if(isset($notification->data['ad_object']))
    <a href="#">{{$notification->data['user_name']}} posted a new ad  "{{$notification->data['ad_object']}}"</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Glad to have helped